# Adding Google Map Search and Marking the Address when someone registers on React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-google-maps

I am creating a register page where a company can sign up for my website so that other companies can view their profiles with what they do, locations, events, etc. I am creating the Register page on my React JS and I've gotten the Google Maps on my page, the only problem is that it doesn't have the Search where you can search for a company address and add it to the profile so that others can see where they are in case anyone wants do anything with them. Here is my Register page code:

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, } from '@react-google-maps/api';





const initialState = {
  company: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  isMember: true,
}

  const Register = () => {

    const containerStyle = {
      width: '400px',
      height: '400px'
    };
    
    const center = {
      lat: -3.745,
      lng: -38.523
    };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

  // global state and useNavigate
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target)
  }

    return (
        <body class="page-template-default page page-id-13">
        <header class="site-header">
              <div class="container">
              <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a></h1>
                         <div class="site-header__util">
                                        </div>
                </div>
                </header>

    <div class="page-banner">
     <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style={ { backgroundImage: "url('connection.jpg')" } }></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Register</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
            <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container container--narrow page-section">
  <h2 class="headline headline--tiny">Want to join and connect with companies? Sign up and get your company out there:</h2>
  
    <label class="header">Profile Photo:</label>
      <input id="image" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture></input>
    <label class="company-name">Company Name</label>
      <div class="company-input">
        <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Company"></input>
      </div>
    <label class="company-email">Email</label>
          <div class="email-input">
          <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Email"></input>
          </div>

     <label class="company-map">Map</label>   
<div class="map-input">
    
  <LoadScript
    googleMapsApiKey='API HERE'>
      
    
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={10}
        >
          { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */ }
          <></>
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>

            </div>  
    </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
                  <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">
                    <div class="group">
                      <div class="site-footer__col-one">
                        <h1 class="school-logo-text school-logo-text--alt-color">
                          <a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
                        </h1>
                        <p><a class="site-footer__link" href="index.html">706-263-0175</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </footer>

</body>
    )
}


export default Register
```

I have tried using HTML inputs to add a search bar but I want it inside the Google Maps box instead of outside. I have tried using other imports to see if I can add more code to add a search and markers but I keep getting errors when saving the code. Here is what I have tried:

```
import {React, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, StandaloneSearchBox, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';






const initialState = {
  company: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  isMember: true,
}

  let markerArray = [];
  const Register = React.Component {

    state = {
      currentLocation: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
      markers: [],
      bounds: null
    };
  
    onMapLoad = map => {
      navigator?.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        ({ coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } }) => {
          const pos = { lat, lng };
          this.setState({ currentLocation: pos });
        }
      );
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", () => {
        console.log(map.getBounds());
        this.setState({ bounds: map.getBounds() });
      });
    };
  
    onSBLoad = ref => {
      this.searchBox = ref;
    };
  
    onPlacesChanged = () => {
      markerArray = [];
      let results = this.searchBox.getPlaces();
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        let place = results[i].geometry.location;
        markerArray.push(place);
      }
      this.setState({ markers: markerArray });
      console.log(markerArray);
    };

    const containerStyle = {
      width: '400px',
      height: '400px'
    };
    
    const center = {
      lat: -3.745,
      lng: -38.523
    };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

  // global state and useNavigate
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target)
  }

    return (
        <body class="page-template-default page page-id-13">
        <header class="site-header">
              <div class="container">
              <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a></h1>
                         <div class="site-header__util">
                                        </div>
                </div>
                </header>

    <div class="page-banner">
     <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style={ { backgroundImage: "url('connection.jpg')" } }></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Register</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
            <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container container--narrow page-section">
  <h2 class="headline headline--tiny">Want to join and connect with companies? Sign up and get your company out there:</h2>
  
    <label class="header">Profile Photo:</label>
      <input id="image" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture></input>
    <label class="company-name">Company Name</label>
      <div class="company-input">
        <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Company"></input>
      </div>
    <label class="company-email">Email</label>
          <div class="email-input">
          <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Email"></input>
          </div>

     <label class="company-map">Map</label>   
<div class="map-input">
    
  <LoadScript
    googleMapsApiKey='API HERE'>
      
      <div>
        <div id="searchbox">
          <StandaloneSearchBox
            onLoad={this.onSBLoad}
            onPlacesChanged={this.onPlacesChanged}
            bounds={this.state.bounds}
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search Address"
              
            />
          </StandaloneSearchBox>
        </div>
        <br />
        </div>
    
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={this.state.currentLocation}
          zoom={10}
        >
          {this.state.markers.map((mark, index) => (
              <Marker key={index} position={mark} />
            ))}
          <></>
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>

            </div>  
    </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
                  <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">
                    <div class="group">
                      <div class="site-footer__col-one">
                        <h1 class="school-logo-text school-logo-text--alt-color">
                          <a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
                        </h1>
                        <p><a class="site-footer__link" href="index.html">706-263-0175</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </footer>

</body>
    )
}


export default Register
```

I think the problem of what I have tried is the `const Register = React.Component` which is user defined.

Comment: Can you post the errors you're getting when saving the code?

Comment: I have edited the question to add some code of what I thought would work but gives me errors.